# base64 string doesnt accept at javascript function from android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, base64

I have impleneted a webview in my android app and through that webview i call javascript function.From that function one function accept base 64 string.

But the problem is that the javascript function accept base 64 string of those images whose image size is less than 3 MB.If image size is greater than 3 MB then it doesnt accept base 64 string

The code from android app is as below

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
                String path = getRealPathFromURI(this, selectedImage);
                File img = new File(path);
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(img.getAbsoluteFile());
                    byte[] bytes;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                    int bytesRead;
                    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    try {
                        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    bytes = output.toByteArray();
                    String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Log.v("base abhi111111111", "" + img_str);

                    editor.loadUrl("javascript:getFilePath('" + img_str + "')");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
                String path = getRealPathFromURI(this, selectedImage);
                File img = new File(path);
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(img.getAbsoluteFile());
                    byte[] bytes;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                    int bytesRead;
                    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    try {
                        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    bytes = output.toByteArray();
                    String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

                    Log.v("base abhi", "" + img_str);
                    editor.loadUrl("javascript:getFilePath1('" + img_str + "')");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

and the function in javascript is as follows.that javascript function accept base 64 string of image size less than  MB.

```
getfilepath(file)
  {
  var file1 = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + file;
            console.write(file);
            var imgObj = new Image();
            imgObj.src = file1;
            imgObj.onload = function () {
                var wt1 = this.width;
                var ht1 = this.height;

                if (wt1 < 150 || ht1 < 150) {
                    alert("low quality image!!!..");
                }
                if (wt1 < 550 && ht1 < 400) {
                    canvas11.setWidth(wt1);
                    canvas11.setHeight(ht1);
                }
                if (wt1 > 550 && ht1 > 400) {
                    ht2 = 370;
                    wt2 = (wt1 * 370) / ht1;
                    canvas11.setWidth(wt2);
                    canvas11.setHeight(ht2);
                }
                if (wt1 < 550 && ht1 > 400) {
                    ht2 = 400;
                    wt2 = (wt1 * 400) / ht1;
                    canvas11.setWidth(wt2);
                    canvas11.setHeight(ht2);
                }
                if (wt1 > 550 && ht1 < 400) {
                    wt2 = 550;
                    ht2 = (ht1 * 550) / wt1;
                    canvas11.setWidth(wt2);
                    canvas11.setHeight(ht2);
                }
                document.getElementById('openerImg').click();

                canvas.backgroundColor = '';
                var height1 = canvas11.height;
                var width1 = canvas11.width;
                var image = new fabric.Image(imgObj);
                image.set({
                    width: width1,
                    height: height1
                });
                canvas11.setBackgroundImage(image, canvas11.renderAll.bind(canvas11));

            };

        }
```

Please give solution.I didnt get solution from last 2 months.Please

Thanks a lot in advance

Logcat if i `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 31082250 byte allocation with 4182256 free bytes and 19MB until OOM
                                                                           at java.lang.StringFactory.newStringFromChars(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.toString(AbstractStringBuilder.java:629)
                                                                           at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:663)
                                                                           at com.dhruva.eprintpost.home.Web_Editor.onActivityResult(Web_Editor.java:297)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6492)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3925)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3972)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1537)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
12`

Answer (score 0):

Compress your bitmap or image ,Try this code

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
                String path = getRealPathFromURI(this, selectedImage);
                File img = new File(path);
                Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img)
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
                byte [] bytes=baos.toByteArray();
        String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
               Log.v("base abhi111111111", "" + img_str);
                    editor.loadUrl("javascript:getFilePath('" + img_str + "')");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();
                String path = getRealPathFromURI(this, selectedImage);
                File img = new File(path);
                Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img)
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
                byte [] bytes=baos.toByteArray();
        String img_str = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Log.v("base abhi", "" + img_str);
                    editor.loadUrl("javascript:getFilePath1('" + img_str + "')");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

try to change your manifest these lines `android:largeHeap="true"`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: I tried this one also but i get outofmemoryexception

Comment: i dont want to loss the quality of image

Comment: but i definately say that it give outofmemory error.

Comment: SIr i have updated my question with outofmemory logcat